# Fittind data with shifted Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: fitting, special-functions, polynomials

I am trying to fit data from a simulation to a particular class of polynomials, according to least squares approach.

```
data = Import["Mathematica file.txt", "Table"]
```

The polynomials are the shifted Chebyshev polynomials, that is:
$${\displaystyle T_{n}^{*}(x)=T_{n}(2x-1)~.}$$
How could one use Mathematica to find the coefficients $a_0$, $a_1$ and so on in:
$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n T_{n}(2x-1)$$
which fits the imported data? Is there a way in Mathematica to find the goodness of fit in Mathematica?

Comment: We can use `NMinimize` to minimize norm of difference between `data` and approximation with respect to $a_n$. Better you show example of `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x*Sin[x];

data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

model[m_, x_] := Sum[a[n] ChebyshevT[n, 2 x - 1], {n, 0, m}];

nlm[m_Integer?Positive, x_] :=
 NonlinearModelFit[data, model[m, x], Array[a, m + 1, 0], x]

Manipulate[
 Module[{model = nlm[m, x]},
  Column[{
    Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], model // Normal}, {x, 0, 10},
     PlotRange -> Full,
     ImageSize -> 300,
     Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]},
     PlotLegends -> Placed[{"f[x]", "approx"}, {.475, .7}]],
    model["ParameterTable"]},
   Alignment -> Center,
   ItemSize -> {35, Automatic}]],
 {{m, 4}, 1, 8, 1, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The unformatted array of values from the table are

```
nlm[4, x]["ParameterTableEntries"]

(* {{0.983793, 0.783451, 1.25572, 0.227247}, 
 {2.24593, 0.592713, 3.78923, 0.00160888}, 
 {-0.506845, 0.0754447, -6.7181, 4.93792*10^-6}, 
 {0.0272154, 0.00327794, 8.3026, 3.41441*10^-7}, 
 {-0.000413407, 0.0000450602, -9.17455, 8.98221*10^-8}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me how can I export the parameter table please?

Comment: Use `"ParameterTableEntries"` (see edit)

Comment: @Mark You can use `LinearModelFit` as well: `ts[n_Integer, x_?NumericQ] := ChebyshevT[n, 2 x - 1];
Format[ts[n_, x_]] := Subsuperscript[HoldForm[T], n, "*"][x]; (* Format optional *)
model[m_, x_] := Table[ts[n, x], {n, m}];
nlm[m_Integer?Positive, x_] := LinearModelFit[data, model[m, x], x]`

Answer (score 1):

Shifted Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal on {0,1} with the weight function `1/Sqrt[x-x^2]`.

As the data: `dat` is not known, but we can create an interpolating function:

```
fun[x_]=Interpolation[dat]
```

For an example, we choose `funx[x_]=Sin[2Pi x]`. We can now expand this function in a series of shifted Chebyshev polynomials. The expansion coefficients are given by:

```
Clear[sT, fun, c, approx]
sT[n_, x_] := ChebyshevT[n, 2 x - 1]
fun[x_] := Sin[2 Pi x];
c[n_] := NIntegrate[fun[x] sT[n, x]/Sqrt[x - x^2], {x, 0, 1}]/
    NIntegrate[sT[n, x]^2/Sqrt[x - x^2], {x, 0, 1}] // Simplify // Chop
```

The partial sum tp to n:

```
approx[n_, x_] := Sum[c[i] sT[i, x], {i, 0, n}] // Quiet
```

I put a `quiet` at the end, because this will eventually give some warnings about precision and convergence if, due to symmetry, some coefficients are zero. But these can mostly be ignored. If you want exact results, you may use "Integrate", but this may take a long time.

We can now create the first few partial sums and plot them against the original function:

```
Do[
 f[x_] = approx[i, x];
 Plot[{f[x], fun[x]}, {x, 0, 1}] // Print
 , {i, 1, 5, 2}]
```

[image]